# What is Magnificence?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

On various Enter the Gungeon discussion boards, I've seen reference to a mechanic called "Magnificence". I've never seen this referenced anywhere in game.

I know EtG does have some other hidden stats, such as Coolness ( increases probability of item drops after clearing a room) and Curse (increases probability of jammed enemies, among other effects). Is Magnificence one of these hidden stats? If so, what does it affect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Magnificence](https://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/Quality#Magnificence) is a hidden stat. Basically, it's a mechanic that prevents you from getting too many A or S tier items in a single run. It's similar to Binding of Isaac's "Special Item" mechanic.

### Types

There are two types of Magnificence:

- **Global** -  Every time you *pick up* (not just encounter) an A or S tier item, your global magnificence goes up by 1. This increase is permanent, and can't be removed, even if you drop the item.
- **Chest** - Whenever a red or black chest is generated on the floor, your "chest magnificence" goes up by 1. If you open one of these chests, your chest magnificence goes down by 1.

Combined, these two types make up your **Total Magnificence**.

## Mechanics

If the game tries to generate an item reward for you (either from bosses, chests, shop items, the King's challenge rooms, etc.) and the reward would normally be A or S tier, there is a chance that the item will be rerolled into a lower tier item if your Total Magnificence is 1 or more. The probability increases logarithmically as your TM gets higher.

```
╔═════╤═══════════════════════╗
║ TM  │ Probability of Reroll ║
╟─────┼───────────────────────╢
║  0  │          0%           ║
║  1  │        79.84%         ║
║  2  │        95.53%         ║
║  3  │        98.62%         ║
║  4  │        99.23%         ║
║  5  │        99.34%         ║
╚═════╧═══════════════════════╝
```

## Items

There are no items in the game that alter your Magnificence value directly, but the [Seven-Leaf Clover](https://enterthegungeon.gamepedia.com/Seven-Leaf_Clover) does bypass the mechanics a little bit. Once you have the item, any future chests generated during floor creation will always be either red or black. Red and black chests *always* drop items of A or S tier, so you will have the opportunity to collect more than the typical number of high-quality items. Other rewards, such as boss items or chests that appear after clearing a room, are still affected by Magnificence and the reroll chance.